# Importing variables into a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll, dllimport

A little background; I'm writing a plugin system for a game engine that will have the main engine code running from the exe (provided by a library, say engine.lib). I want to be able to export some global variables from engine.lib into a plugin dll that's loaded at run-time.

So for example;

**engine.lib**: Has a variable called g_foobar that is initialised at some point by the exe that statically links to engine.lib

**plugin.dll**: This also statically links to engine.lib as I want to be able to manipulate g_foobar using the various classes within engine.lib

Obviously when the plugin loads it has it's own instance of **g_foobar** which isn't initialised to the same as the **g_foobar** within the exe.

I want to (with a bit of dllexport/dllimport magic) make the dynamic linker link up the two symbols so that the **g_foobar** within the dll points to the same memory as the one in the exe.

Some code I've had a play with (3 VS projects, exe, enginelib, plugindll):

**Header.h**

```
#pragma once

#if !defined(__ISALIB__)
    #if defined(__ISADLL__)
        #define API __declspec(dllimport)
    #else 
        #define API __declspec(dllexport)
    #endif
#else
    #define API 
#endif 

class API CFoobar
{
public:
    CFoobar(int i);
    int m_iDave;
};

extern API CFoobar* g_foobar;
```

**EXE.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Header.h"

typedef void (*FooFN)();

CFoobar s_Foo(100);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    g_foobar = &s_Foo;

    HMODULE h = LoadLibraryA("plugin.dll");

    FooFN func = (FooFN)GetProcAddress(h, "Foobar");

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

**plugindll.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Foobar()
{
    printf("VALUE: %d\n", g_foobar->m_iDave);
}
```

**enginelib.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"

CFoobar* g_foobar = NULL;

CFoobar::CFoobar(int i)
    :m_iDave(i)
{   
}
```

Even after compiling the exe/lib/dll in various ways (altering the API define), I can't get the output to print '100', it will always print '0' because I'm statically linking with the engine.lib.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get this working because there's surely something obvious I'm doing wrong.

NOTE: Removing the use of the static library isn't really an option due to the way the rest of the codebase works.

Cheers.

Comment: Your EXE has its own copy of g_foobar, linked in from enginelib.  No sharing.  Having to use LoadLibrary() makes it unfriendly, you'll need to export a SetFooBar() function so the EXE can set the pointer that the DLL uses.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there are two copies of the variable, but what I'm looking for is for the dynamic linker to make g_foobar in the dll point to the same memory space as the g_foobar in the host exe so I can access whatever the host app has set it to.

Comment: Well, sure, it would be wholeheckofalot easier if you let it dynamically link.  But you don't and use LoadLibrary().  You then have to link yourself with GetProcAddress(), you already know how to do that.  You can't have it both ways, such is the price of plugins.

Comment: @HansPassant I know I'm calling GetProcAddress(), that's just in my quick example as I'm calling a known exported function in the DLL. Does calling LoadLibrary stop the dynamic link from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long look at this and talking with some people at work we managed to drop the need for the static lib as I don't think it's possible to do.

So based on my example code above, enginelib becomes a DLL, and the header API block becomes:

```
#if defined(__ISADLL__)
    #define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
    #define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And plugindll and exe both link to the .lib produced by the enginelib dll build.